# Two StreamBuilderon on one screen with default empty screen shown when neither has data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a Split View with two ListViews, one of them showing Tasks which are not completed and the second one containing completed tasks. I managed to make this work with a Column containing two Streambuilder. The problem I don't know how to solve is how to show a single default empty screen when neither of the two Streams have any values, due to the way Flutter works, I can't just return null. So I end up having two Empty default screens in my Column and on my screen.

What would be the right approach to make something like shown in the GIF with Firestore?
If I need to work with a single Stream and filter it inside dart, how can I make it work with ListView ?
I'd highly appreciate an example.
My Job class contains a boolean value **jobDone** which tells me in which list the Job has to go.

[image]

My current code:

```
return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
          stream: getPendingJobsStream(database),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
            ...
            );
          },
        ),

        ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('Completed Tasks'),
          children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<Job>>(
            stream: getCompletedJobsStream(database),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return ListItemsBuilder<Job>(
                ...
              );
            },
          ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for snapshot state

```
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
             if(snapshot.connectionState ==ConnectionState.waiting){
            return Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator();
             }
          if(snapshot.connectionState ==ConnectionState.done){
//check if snapshot has data
               if(snapshot.hasData){
          
                  return ListItemsBuilder<Job>(   ..
```